# Does the python extension of vscode support autocompletion for eggs?

Tags: python, autocomplete, visual-studio-code

From what I've seen, eggs python packages are not supported for autocompletion in vscode (centos 7, vscode 1.25.1, vscode python 2018.7.1, python 2.7.14, jedi 0.12.0).

Can this be confirmed? Or am I missing something in the configuration?

Just adding here that otherwise autocompletion works fine for non eggs packages.

The eggs are not part of the workspace folder and are added via the "python.autoComplete.extraPaths" setting:

```
{
  "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["/eggs/mypackage-0.1-py2.7.egg"]
}
```